# Site is redirecting multiple times when added new rule to .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have added some new rules into my .htaccess file and after adding those rules my site is now redirecting 2 times is there a way through which I can keep my rules and my site will redirect only once here is the rule written in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have checked the redirection from the following [site](http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php).

I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am pretty sure with `RewriteBase /blog/` you dont need `RewriteRule . /blog/index.php`  Unless it's `/blog/blog/index.php`  You should be able to do just `RewriteRule . /index.php` As that is the point of `RewriteBase`

Comment: Sir I need it as when I remove that /index.php it redirects me nowhere and lands me back on the same page

Comment: Which framework you are using ..?

Comment: Sir I am working on wordpress

Comment: @RaghbendraNayakSystematix - obviously this is wordpress.

Comment: @MohsinAbbas - I didn't see the `.` so I was thinking it was the otherside of the rule ... lol

Comment: Lol actually I just solved my issue on my own just posting my answer actually there were two .htacces file one on the root directory and other inside the blog directory by changing rules in my root .htaccess file solved my issu

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I was not seeing it.  Recently I have been getting away from using complicated rewrite rules  ... lol so I'm a bit rusty.  I used to use them a lot more before i discovered routing, but they are hard to maintain.

Comment: Ah don't worry it happens

Comment: I would either post an answer or delete the question, just so it doesn't sit open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my issue and resolved it. The real issue was that there were two .htaccess files one on the root directory and second one in my /blog directory I just changed some rules from /blog/.htaccess and added some new rules in my root/.htaccess file solved this multiple redirect problem here are the updated rules of both of my .htaccess.

**Root .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hkdcrandom\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hkdcrandom\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

**/blog/.htaccess (Updated rules)**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

These rules solved the problem in my case hope it will help other as well in the future